# Where to find samples of modern German handwritten text?

Tags: resource, handwriting

Googling mostly reveals some curly Old German scripts, beautiful, but hard to read and write.

How do pupils write text in their copybooks today? I assume there should be some simplistic, streamlined cursive letters suitable for quick writing (and reading). Writing print letters by hand is slow and clumsy.

Is there a:

- table, showing each letter in handwriting, together with instruction how to draw it (where to start, how to connect with the next letter, etc.);
- sample of the text according to such table (accurate, legible)?

---

*Mein Versuch den Text ins Deutsche zu übersetzen: (Bitte korrigieren Sie Fehler)*

Ich habe im Internet nach deutschen schreibschriftlichen Textbeispielen gesucht, aber meistens altdeutsche Dokumente oder kalligrafische Texte in Kartengrüßen gefunden.

Wie schreiben deutsche Schüler in ihren Heften? Ich glaube, dass es eine einfache, laufende Schrift gibt, die es ermöglicht, viel Text zu schreiben, und gut lesbar ist. Es ist unbequem und langsam, Druckschrift mit der Hand zu schreiben.

Gibt es:

- eine Tabelle, die zeigt, wie man jeden Buchstaben zeichnen kann (mit Pfeilen, Verbindungen zwischen Buchstaben, usw.);
- ein Textbeispiel nach der Tabelle (lesbar, ohne Schnörkel)?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11027/how-different-is-german-handwriting-from-americans

Comment: The pictures in [German Wikipedia’s _Schreibschrift_ article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibschrift) should provide a first impression. Individual hands differ a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Es gibt in Deutschland drei Arten von "Schreibschrift":

- die [**Schulausgangsschrift**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulausgangsschrift) (SAS), die in den östlichen Bundesländern mehr verbreitet ist
  [image: Wikimedia Commons: Schulausgangsschrift]
  [image: http://www.unkonzentrierte-schueler.de/Documents/SAS.pdf]
- die [**lateinische Ausgangsschrift**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ausgangsschrift) (LA), die älteste Schulschreibschrift
  [image: Wikimedia Commons: lateinische Ausgangsschrift]
  <sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/a5/La-ges.jpg))</sub>

[image: http://www.unkonzentrierte-schueler.de/Documents/LA.pdf]

- die [**vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vereinfachte_Ausgangsschrift) (VA), die gebräuchlichste Schulschreibschrift, die auch zur Zeit in der Schule gelehrt wird
  [image: Wikimedia Commons: Vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift]
  [image: http://www.unkonzentrierte-schueler.de/Documents/VA.pdf]

Auf [folgendender Webseite](http://uks-material.de/neue_website/) gibt es Übungsblätter zu allen drei Schreibschriftarten:
Im „Buchstabentraining“ wird gezeigt, wie jeder Buchstabe geschrieben wird, dann folgt das „Schreibtraining“ mit Wörtern.
Man kann jeweils auswählen, welche Schriftart man lernen möchte, die vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift, die lateinische Ausgangsschrift oder die Schulausgangsschrift.

Ich würde dir empfehlen die vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift (VA) zu nehmen.

Comment: @Crissov, danke für die Ergänzung der Bilder

Comment: Leider zeigen die Bilder bis auf „Schulausgangsschrift“ keine verbundenen Wörter und das zur LA ist wirklich nicht gut. Der Antwort fehlt vielleicht noch der Hinweis, dass in verschiedenen (Bundes-)Ländern geplant oder diskutiert wird, die Schreibschrift nicht mehr verpflichtend, sondern stattdessen eine druckschriftnahe [Grundschrift](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundschrift) zu lehren.

Comment: Ich hab noch die Beispielbilder von der Übrungswebseite hinzugefügt.

Comment: Die "vereinfachte" Ausgangsschrift ist heiß diskutiert, nicht alle Pädagogen empfehlen sie, weil sie den Schreibfluss weniger unterstützt als die LA. Die Grundschule meiner Kinder (sonst extrem progressiv in Ansatz und Methodik) lehrt bewusst die LA. Aussage von dort: die LA ist ein geeigneterer Ausgangspunkt zur Entwicklung einer gut lesbaren, flüssigen individuellen Handschrift als die VA. (Die aus meiner *persönlichen* Sicht auch noch potthässlich ist, aber das tut nichts zur Sache.)

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass das alte z mit Unterlänge noch irgendwo gelehrt wird. Klein-Z ist wie Groß-Z, nur klein.

Comment: Actually I've never seen _anyone_ writing the `tz` like in that last picture the `Vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift`. It looks soooo artificially made complicated ... it's also not what I learned at school. I already learned a simplified version, which looks more or less like a printed letter.

Comment: @unser unknown and @ Zelphir, did you  find the small z in Vi.'s answer? Vi. wrote "trotz" in VA

Comment: @Iris Now I see. Well that's very unusual, never seen anyone doing that tbh. Also looks like a `g` instead. Too many similarities in that style. Also, if that's supposed to be a "good starting point for developing a readable handwriting" ... ^^
It just doesn't make sense to teach children something they'll discard later in life, most likely. Instead they should just teach children the writing they'll use anyway, so that they can practice on that already.

Answer (score 4):

Ich habe einfach einmal einen Hefteintrag für Dich abfotografiert, falls du ein echtes Beispiel brauchst. Meine Schrift ist zwar jetzt nicht die schönste, aber immerhin Schreibschrift. :) (Mein Bruder behauptet, er könne sie nicht lesen.) Viel Spaß beim Entziffern!
[image: Hefteintrag Deutsch 9. Klasse]

---

## Transkript (von Vi. erstellt, von palsch korrigiert)

### Kontrovers: 9a diskutiert

Forts. HE vom 22.2.16

Liebe oder Recht? -> (Heirat)

Probleme in der Diskussion:
Argumente zu wenig ausgearbeitet
Bsp. überwiegen; Wiederholung der Arg. (Argumente, das habe ich ein bisschen komisch abgekürzt)
         Inhalt

pers. Überzeugungskraft
Argumente zu wenig aufeinander bezogen
Einbeziehen aller Teilnehmer
Vorbereitung der Argumente
         pers. Auftreten

1 der Argumente ausformulieren: HA

In der Novelle [...] siegt am Ende die Liebe, denn zwei der
Hauptpersonen heiraten. Trotz der Verdachte gegen Olivier wird
die Anklage fallen gelassen und er kommt frei, sodass er seine
Geliebte wiedersieht und heiraten kann. Der Umstand, dass die
beiden Paris verlassen müssen, macht ihnen nichts aus, solange sie
zusammen sind. Zum Zeichen des abschließenden Sieges der Liebe
erfährt der Leser von diesem Geschehen erst am Ende der Geschichte.

Scuderi als Detektivin

```
(Vorgehens -)-----(Scuderi)------(Beweg -)
    \---------(Konflikt)-------------/
```

Comment: Ich schmiere echt ein bisschen, merke ich gerade.

Comment: OK, das ist vielleicht nicht so lesbar, aber es bildet die Realität ab.

Comment: pal sch, das ist die vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift, oder? Ich kann's lesen und ich habe noch die lateinische Ausgangsschrift in der Schule gelernt.

Comment: @Iris Ja, sieht für mich auch so aus. ;-) In der Grundschule hat man halt nicht gesagt "Das ist die vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift.", sondern "Ihr wollt doch schneller schreiben können, oder? Probiert das doch mal."

Comment: @palsch, Ich habe dieses Text tippen [versucht](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13879). Ich verstehe aber wenig. Korrigieren Sie bitte.

Comment: @Vi. Ich habe den Text korrigiert, waren nur kleine Fehler. :-)

Comment: @Vi. Der Text ist ein Hefteintrag im Fach Deutsch. In dieser Stunde haben wir eine Lektüre besprochen, die wir davor gelesen hatten: Titel: Das Fräulein von Scuderi. Unserer Deutschlehrerin ist (leider) nichts besseres eingefallen, als uns über das Thema "Was siegt in der Lektüre? Liebe oder Recht?" in einer Diskussionsrunde diskutieren zu lassen, deren Fehler wir in der Stunde darauf besprochen haben. Das ging dann direkt in das Gebiet der Argumentation über und als Hausaufgabe (HA) haben wir dann eine solche aufbekommen - siehe alles unter "1 der Argumente ausformulieren".

Comment: Und übrigens, @Vi., "Text" ist vom grammatischen Geschlecht her männlich, also ist es _der_ Text (nicht dieses, sondern diesen Text im Kommentar).

Answer (score 0):

`Iris` already mentioned some, but actually ...

Many people simply write print letters, which have some resemblance of the writings `Iris` has shown or the one `pal sch` has in his notebook. I also write printed letters, since my handwriting is not consistent enough for the so called *Schreibschrift*, which connects all the letters of one word. I find the *Schreibschrift* to be simply too cumbersome to really use it and there are some "letter connections", which don't really fit. One has to make them fit somehow and it doesn't feel like a complete thought-through system. Additionally it's arguable harder to read than printed letters, puts more strain on the eyes.

The *Schreibschrift* will probably disappear from schools in the future at some point. No loss if you ask me.

Comment: Proper handwriting should increase writing speed, yet preserving legibility. Writing block letters requires too many strokes. Trying to adapt block letters for smoother writing (making them curved and connected) **is** creating a handwriting font.

Comment: @Vi. In my opinion it does never increase the speed of writing objectively, because _Schreibschrift_ letters simply contain longer lines. name a block letter, that contains more strokes, which are not _on the path your pen goes_ when writing the _Schreibschrift_ version of that letter. I think there isn't even a single one. I've also never seen a _Schreibschrift_ document, which is more readable, no matter how good the handwriting is.
All kinds of documents use block letters, partly because their printing history, but largely also because readability is higher than for _Schreibschrift_.

Comment: @Vi. Readability will also be affected by everyone having their own way of writing _Schreibschrift_ (although also partly true for block letters, it is more so in _Schreibschrift_). When someone hands me a text with _Schreibschrift_, first thing is an inner sigh, because I'll need to get used to their style of writing, instead of just reading block letters.

Comment: @Vi. What I meant by "resemblance of the writings Iris has shown" is obviously not exactly the same or all letters connected, but _some_ letters connected. Don't mix up the term `handwriting` and `Schreibschrift` here. There are differences.